# figure out math formula for spaces in pascal diamond project

Tags: command-line, pascal, freepascal

How is it going guys ? 
I've written a program that "draws" diamond in the command line (it's a part of my homework). For spaces inside the diamond I was given a formula "1 + 2(k-2) or 2k -3 , where k is line number", but I don't understand how this formula was created. Could anyone explain it ?

```
program diamond;
var
    n, k, h, i: integer;
begin
    repeat 
        write('Enter the diamond''s height (positive odd): ');
        readln(h);
    until (h > 0) and (h mod 2 = 1);
    n := h div 2;
    for k := 1 to n + 1 do
    begin 
        for i := 1 to n + 1 - k do
            write(' ');
        write('*');            
        if k > 1 then 
        begin 
        for i := 1 to 2*k - 3 do
            write(' ');
        write('*')
        end;
        writeln
    end;
    for k := n downto 1 do 
    begin 
    for i := 1 to n + 1 - k do
        write(' ');
    write('*');
    if k > 1 then
    begin 
        for i := 1 to 2*k - 3 do
            write(' ');
        write('*')
    end;
    writeln
    end
end.
```

Comment: What *do* you understand about this formula?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't understand it at all. It is correct for sure, but I can't figure out how it works

Comment: So this is really a _math_ question, a geometry question? Maybe you wanna head to Math.SE? By the way, `n mod 2 = 1` is usually written as `odd(n)` and to output `n` spaces you can simply write `write('':n)` (without the need for a loop).

Comment: I've already figured it out. It's a simple, but modified arithmetic progression An=A1-d(n-2). Usually we would use (n-1), but because we need to substract 2 stars from each line (starting from the second one, as this formula works for k>1), we use (n-2)

Answer (score 0):

I've already figured it out. It's a simple, but modified arithmetic progression An=A1-d(n-2). Usually we would use (n-1), but because we need to substract 2 stars from each line (starting from the second one, as this formula works for k>1), we use (n-2)